# Центрирование текста в CSS по форме буквы V

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

У меня есть эта изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я знаю, что  можно использовать `text-align: center`, и я мог бы даже сделать каждую строку диапазоном и постепенно увеличивать отступы, но есть ли свойство, о котором я не знаю, например, центр от центра или что-то подобное?

Это кажется очевидным, но я просто не могу придумать разумного решения.

**UPDATE**

Вопрос был в том, что на картинке текст имеет тенденцию становиться короче к низу, как и буква V, поэтому текст начинается широким и постепенно становится уже.

Я никогда не видел, чтобы подобное было сделано, поэтому было очень интересно узнать решение.

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Centring text in CSS within a “V” shape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67229061/7394871) от участника  [@Jesse Orange](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6744223/jesse-orange).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67229061/7394871

Answer (score 4):

`shape-outside` может это сделать:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:flex; /* это нужно для процентной высоты */
}

.box {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align:justify;
}

.box > div,
.box::before{
  height:150%; /* должно быть не менее 100%, но мы считаем больше, чтобы избежать переполнения*/
  width:100px; /* отрегулировать это */
}
  
.box > div {
  float:right;
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#0000 50%,#000 0);
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  float:left;
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(to bottom left,#0000 50%,#000 0);
}

/* ниже не нужно, это только для иллюстрации формы
    раскомментируйте это, чтобы увидеть, что происходит
.box > div {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#0000 50%,red 0);
}
.box::before {
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom left,#0000 50%,green 0);
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">
    <div></div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum pretium lacus ipsum, at placerat nunc sollicitudin scelerisque. Donec vulputate ex odio, et facilisis nisi tristique et. Maecenas tortor nisi, euismod et tellus sit amet, tincidunt congue
    eros. Nam et viverra magna, id ultricies augue.
  </div>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67229202/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

**White-space: break-spaces**.

При соответствующей ширине получится:

```css
#text {
  padding:10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 600px;
  white-space: break-spaces;
  background-color:gray;
  color: silver;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">“Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam sodales ultrices nibh
at bibendum. Vivamus in volutpat diam. Vivamus ut mi non leo vehicula mattis.
Maecenas nec dolor id tellus consequat laoreet nec sit amet lacus.”

Jane from Cool Business Ltd</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67229143/7394871) от участника  [@mplungjan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295783/mplungjan).</sub>